# read XML file from assets folder for tree view?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Hi need to run a hierarchical file which is in assets folder in tree view . I did submit Folderstucture fragemets here also.
Actually i have to pass  the data without making any hard code you can see in case 1 ()... Please help me .Sorry for bad example any needs i can provide you again hard copy.
trying hard to do it . Please give me an example for android studio. Thank you.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<de>
    <haw_hamburg>
                <bt7>
                    <r1485>
                        <devices>
                            <device id='135165'>
                                <device_name>TV living room</device_name>
                                <id_type>1</id_type>
                                <id_type_device>1</id_type_device>
                                <model>SmartTV LED  47"</model>
                                <owner></owner>
                                <connectivity>wifi</connectivity>
                                <address>192.168.1.100</address>
                                <info>
                                    <screen>
                                        <height>1080</height>
                                        <width>1920</width>
                                    </screen>
                                    <speaker>true</speaker>
                                    <input>
                                        <item>
                                            <name></name>
                                            <id></id>
                                            <unit></unit>
                                            <sensortype></sensortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </input>
                                    <output>
                                        <item>
                                            <name></name>
                                            <id></id>
                                            <unit></unit>
                                            <actuatortype></actuatortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </output>
                                    <wifi>
                                        <mac>3C:CD:93:74:62:56</mac>
                                    </wifi>
                                    <ethernet>
                                        <mac_eth>4D:CF:93:23:61:17</mac_eth>
                                    </ethernet>
                                    <rf>false</rf>
                                </info>
                            </device>
                            <device id='165165'>
                                <device_name>TV room</device_name>
                                <id_type>1</id_type>
                                <id_type_device>1</id_type_device>
                                <model>SmartTV LED  28"</model>
                                <owner></owner>
                                <connectivity>eth</connectivity>
                                <address></address>
                                <info>
                                    <screen>
                                        <height>768</height>
                                        <width>1366</width>
                                    </screen>
                                    <speaker>true</speaker>
                                    <input>
                                        <item>
                                            <name></name>
                                            <id></id>
                                            <unit></unit>
                                            <sensortype></sensortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </input>
                                    <output>
                                        <item>
                                            <name></name>
                                            <id></id>
                                            <unit></unit>
                                            <actuatortype></actuatortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </output>
                                    <wifi>
                                        <mac>3C:CD:93:74:62:56</mac>
                                    </wifi>
                                    <ethernet>
                                        <mac_eth>4D:CF:93:23:61:17</mac_eth>
                                    </ethernet>
                                    <rf>false</rf>
                                </info>
                            </device>
                            <device id='546161'>
                                <device_name>Temperature sensor kitchen</device_name>
                                <id_type>3</id_type>
                                <id_type_device>4</id_type_device>
                                <model>Sensor temperature</model>
                                <owner></owner>
                                <connectivity>radio</connectivity>
                                <address></address>
                                <info>
                                    <screen>
                                        <height></height>
                                        <width></width>
                                    </screen>
                                    <speaker></speaker>
                                    <input>
                                        <item>
                                            <name></name>
                                            <id></id>
                                            <unit></unit>
                                            <sensortype></sensortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </input>
                                    <output>
                                        <item>
                                            <name></name>
                                            <id></id>
                                            <unit></unit>
                                            <actuatortype></actuatortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </output>
                                    <wifi>
                                        <mac>3C:CD:93:74:62:56</mac>
                                    </wifi>
                                    <ethernet>
                                        <mac_eth>4D:CF:93:23:61:17</mac_eth>
                                    </ethernet>
                                    <rf>true</rf>
                                </info>
                            </device>
                            <device id='459863'>
                                <device_name>John's Phone</device_name>
                                <id_type>2</id_type>
                                <id_type_device>3</id_type_device>
                                <model>Samsung Galaxy Note 4</model>
                                <owner>2</owner>
                                <connectivity>wifi</connectivity>
                                <address>192.168.1.100</address>
                                <info>
                                    <screen>
                                        <height>2560</height>
                                        <width>1440</width>
                                    </screen>
                                    <speaker>true</speaker>
                                    <input>
                                        <item>
                                            <name></name>
                                            <id></id>
                                            <unit></unit>
                                            <sensortype></sensortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </input>
                                    <output>
                                        <item>
                                            <name></name>
                                            <id></id>
                                            <unit></unit>
                                            <actuatortype></actuatortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </output>
                                    <wifi>
                                        <mac>3C:CD:93:74:62:56</mac>
                                    </wifi>
                                    <ethernet>
                                        <mac_eth></mac_eth>
                                    </ethernet>
                                    <rf>false</rf>
                                </info>
                            </device>
                            <device id='189964'>
                                <device_name>Heating</device_name>
                                <id_type>1</id_type>
                                <id_type_device>5</id_type_device>
                                <model>Mitsubishi Electric</model>
                                <owner></owner>
                                <connectivity>wifi</connectivity>
                                <address>192.168.1.28</address>
                                <info>
                                    <screen>
                                        <height></height>
                                        <width></width>
                                    </screen>
                                    <speaker></speaker>
                                    <input>
                                        <item>
                                            <name>Humidity sensor</name>
                                            <id>1</id>
                                            <unit>mb</unit>
                                            <sensortype>1</sensortype>
                                        </item>
                                        <item>
                                            <name>Temperature sensor</name>
                                            <id>2</id>
                                            <unit>ยบC</unit>
                                            <sensortype>2</sensortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </input>
                                    <output>
                                        <item>
                                            <name>RGB led lights</name>
                                            <id>3</id>
                                            <unit></unit>
                                            <actuatortype>1</actuatortype>
                                        </item>
                                    </output>
                                    <wifi>
                                        <mac>3C:XD:93:94:61:46</mac>
                                    </wifi>
                                    <ethernet>
                                        <mac_eth></mac_eth>
                                    </ethernet>
                                    <rf>false</rf>
                                </info>
                            </device>
                        </devices>
                    </r1485>
                </bt7>
    </haw_hamburg>
</de>
```

---

```
package haw.com.smarthomelib;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;
public class FolderStructureFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView statusBar;
    private AndroidTreeView tView;
    private String Type;
    private String Value;
    private int check = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * setContentView(int) with a layout resource defining our UI
     * using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets in that UI
     * that we need to interact with
     */
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_default, null, false);
        ViewGroup containerView = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        statusBar = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.status_bar);
        TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();
        TreeNode Country = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_location, "Germany",""));

        TreeNode City = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_location_city, "Hamburg",""));
        TreeNode University = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_gps_fixed, "HAW Hamburg",""));
        TreeNode Buliding1 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_gps_not_fixed, "Berliner Tor 1",""));
        TreeNode Building2 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_gps_not_fixed, "Berliner Tor 3",""));
        TreeNode Building3 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_gps_not_fixed, "Berliner Tor 5",""));
        TreeNode Building4 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_hotel, "Berliner Tor 7",""));
        University.addChildren(Buliding1, Building2, Building3, Building4);

        TreeNode ServerRoom = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_laptop, "Server room",""));
        TreeNode ProjectGroup1 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_group, "Group 1",""));
        //TreeNode ProjectGroup2 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_group, "Group 2",""));
       // TreeNode ProjectGroup3 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_group, "Group 3",""));
        //TreeNode ProjectGroup4 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_group, "Group 4",""));
        City.addChild(University);
        Country.addChildren(City);
        root.addChildren(Country);
        Building4.addChild(ServerRoom);
       // ServerRoom.addChildren(ProjectGroup1, ProjectGroup2, ProjectGroup3, ProjectGroup4);
        ServerRoom.addChildren(ProjectGroup1);
        fillFolder(ProjectGroup1);
       // fillFolder(ProjectGroup2);
        tView = new AndroidTreeView(getActivity(), root);
        tView.setDefaultAnimation(true);
        // 2Dscroll
        //tView.setUse2dScroll(true);
        tView.setDefaultContainerStyle(R.style.TreeNodeStyleCustom);
        tView.setDefaultViewHolder(IconTreeItemHolder.class);
        tView.setDefaultNodeClickListener(nodeClickListener);
        tView.setDefaultNodeLongClickListener(nodeLongClickListener);
        containerView.addView(tView.getView());

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String state = savedInstanceState.getString("tState");
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(state)) {
                tView.restoreState(state);
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.expandAll:
                tView.expandAll();
                break;

            case R.id.collapseAll:
                tView.collapseAll();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void fillFolder(TreeNode folder) {

        switch (check) {

            case 1: {
                TreeNode file1 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_check_circle_blank, "TempIn", "-5°c"));
                TreeNode file2 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_check_circle_blank, "TempOut", "25°c"));
                TreeNode file3 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_check_circle_blank, "Humidity", "35%"));
                TreeNode file4 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_check_circle_blank, "Battery", "62%"));

                folder.addChildren(file1, file2, file3,file4 );
                break;
            }

            case 2:
                try {
                    //System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/student/Desktop/Configuration.xml");
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    // System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
                    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Sensors");
                    //System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                        //System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
                        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                            //System.out.println("Sensors id : "
                            //        + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                            Type = eElement.getElementsByTagName("type")
                                    .item(0).getTextContent();
                            Value = eElement.getElementsByTagName("value")
                                    .item(0).getTextContent();
                            TreeNode file = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_check_circle_blank, Type, Value));
                            folder.addChildren(file);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

    private TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener nodeClickListener = new TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value) {
            IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem item = (IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem) value;
            statusBar.setText("Last clicked: " + item.text);
        }
    };

    private TreeNode.TreeNodeLongClickListener nodeLongClickListener = new TreeNode.TreeNodeLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(TreeNode node, Object value) {
            IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem item = (IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem) value;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long click: " + item.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("tState", tView.getSaveState());
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading a file from assets, parsing it and puting results in a tree are three different things. You did not tell where you need help. Please edit your post.

Comment: I actually need to putting results in a tree . But not making hard coded like this one   TreeNode City = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_location_city, "Hamburg",""));   its better i can read directly from XML file which is in my assets folder